# Disabling browsers menu bar except "Bookmark", "New Tab" and "New Window"

Tags: browser, script, shell-script

Good Evening. I have a project for my office and I need help i.e disabling the Menu Bar, Shortcut Keys and Command Bar for Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome but Users can save and view their favorites web sites and also they can open the New Tab and New Window in the browser. Is there any script to do the exact thing? Actually I can do a few with the help of Gpedit.msc but the whole purpose is not fulfilling. If anybody can help me would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,
Pinaki

Comment: With gpedit natively maybe for IE on some of those settings to enforce so the end user cannot change. Otherwise find the correlated registry settings for all these settings for all these web browser and then you could likely push the registry settings at login or startup or something based on whatever level the reg settings apply to the system.

Comment: Thank you McDonald's for your valuable suggestion. what I found is I can disable the Menu Bar from Gpedit.msc but one new challenge is with the help of shortcut keys users can control all the options. I am wondering how to disable the browser shortcut keys.